# How to pass extra params to frameworkComponents

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

frameworkComponents: {
        squareRenderer: SquareRenderer,
}

how can I add extra parameters to SquareRenderer component?

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Wrap the component and pass whatever props you want:

```js
const WrappedSquareRenderer = () => <SquareRenderer banana={banana} />;

frameworkComponents: { squareRenderer: WrappedSquareRenderer, }
```

Comment: @As3Script feel free to accept the answer if that solves your issue, lol

Comment: this solution doesnt work when the param changes, the aggrid framework doesnt rerenders the react component with the changed param

Comment: Passing a component with props causes ag-grid to undetect getValue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
frameworkComponents: {
      actionsRenderer: (params) => {
        return new ItemRenderer(params, addParameter1, addParameter2);
      },
    }
```

Where ItemRenderer is a react component, you will get a warning because it does not like arrow functions but it works.

Answer (score -1):

const Actions=()=>

frameworkComponents={{CellRenderer: child}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).